# Angular2 loadChildren after webpacked, produces __webpack_require__ is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I have a simple Angular2 app using loadChildren, it works fine during development relying on SystemJs, after webpacking it, and fixing the issue with a webpack loader, the output looks like this

```
path: 'events', component: CoreComponents.MainLayoutComponent, loadChildren: 
   function(){ 
      return  __webpack_require__(125)("EventModule")
   }
```

When I browse to /events, I get

```
TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function
```

I read through webpack repository and found this
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1890

But they say it is closed, don't know where the error is coming if it is closed, I do not use any other loaders besides the simple fix for the loadChildren syntax (similar to this https://github.com/daviddt/angular2-lazy-load-example). When I added a console log before the return statement, it retuend an "object" not a "function"

```
console.log(__webpack_require__(125));
```

returns:

```
1. Object
    1. EventModule:EventModule()
        1. arguments:(...)
        2. caller:(...)
        3. length:0
        4. name:"EventModule"
        5. prototype:Object
        6. __proto__:()
        7. [[FunctionLocation]]:app.js:46194
        8. [[Scopes]]:Scopes[2]
    2. __proto__:Object
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dug deep, and finally found the answer
the line should have been using square brackets!

```
 return  __webpack_require__(125)["EventModule"]
```